# onNewToken() not overridden from superclass FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per the documentation on Firebase, `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is now depreciated thus `onNewToken()` should now be called from `FirebaseMessagingService`. So I updated my FirebaseMessagingService version but it turns out the "supposedly" overridden method `onNewToken(String refreshedToken)` is not called/found.

When I place the cursor on the method here's the error I got: `Method does not override method from it's superclass`

```
public class MyMessangingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(MyMessangingService.class);

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    LOGE(TAG, "Message received");
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String refreshedToken) {
    super.onNewToken(refreshedToken);
    LOGE(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
   }
}
```

Here's my app's gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
```

I know that this (token refresh) can be done in an activity but I'd like to stick with my current implementation, unless of course that's the only way to go.

Comment: I don't observe the same problem.  I can override onNewToken just fine in both Java and Kotlin using 18.0.0.

Comment: @DougStevenson . well I'm still stuck with it. What's your firebase-core version ?

Comment: Did you perform Build->Rebuild? This will clean and rebuild your project. This seems one of those wrong-symbol bugs with Android Studio

Comment: All of my versions are up to date as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). firebase-core should not affect what happens in firebase-messaging.  Rather, it's the other way around, since everything typically depends on core.

Comment: Try navigating to FirebaseMessagingService.  Do you see a onNewToken in there?  What archive is it coming from?

Comment: hey...looks like everything i got to do was to rebuild my project. ...the newToken() is called.